# JQuery add onclick string to anchor that are not of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html code which is loaded by reading some json. Inside that data there are some links.

I need to add `onclick="myfunction();"` to the anchors of these links.

As I don't want any other links to be changed I have added a class to all internal link (Links which are not imported).

What I need is some jquery which would do this:

IF Links have not go `class="internal"` then add onclick="myfunction();"**

So if link looks like:

```
<a href="" class="internal">Click me</a>
```

then nothing is done

but if it's like this:

```
<a href="">Click me</a>
```

then it's changed to this:

```
<a href="" onclick="myfunction();">Click me</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`not` psuedoselector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('a:not(".internal")').on('click', function () {
    // click handler code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

```
$('a').not('.classname').click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just, don't.

Unless you have *very specific reason for using explicit `onclick` attributes on your HTML* (and I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to), just use `$('a:not(.internal)').on('click', myfunction);`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the **this** parameter to your function

```
onclick="myfunction(this);"


function myfunction(elem){
    if(elem.className == '' || elem.className !== 'internal') return;

}
```

Or you can remove your event from the HTML and add it using jQuery..

```
<a href="">Click me</a> then it's changed to this: <a href="" >Click me</a>

$('body').on('click' ,  'a' , function(e) {

     if( e.target.className == '' || e.target.className !== 'internal') e.preventDefault();

     myfunction()
});
```

This will only add the click event that